# Get keyof for an annotated object type

Tags: typescript

If I declare an object such as this one:

```
const values = {
    x: 5,
    y: 6,
};

type Key = keyof typeof values;
```

The `Key` type is `"x" | "y"` which makes a lot of sense since those are the valid keys of the `values` object. However, in this scenario:

```
const values2: {
    [key: string]: number;
} = {
    x: 5,
    y: 6,
};

type Key2 = keyof typeof values2;
```

Then, the `Key2` type is `string | number` which are the valid object key types. This doesn't make a lot of sense because the `values2` object is being declared as having its key always be a `string`.

What could be causing this? And how can I declare an object that is similar to `values2` (as in, I restrict what the type of the objects's values is), and then grab the valid keys as I am doing for the `values` object?

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20values2%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%205%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%206%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Key2%20%3D%20keyof%20typeof%20values2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20values%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%205%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%206%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Key%20%3D%20keyof%20typeof%20values%3B)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but note that if you have `const values2: { [key in string]: number; } = ...` it works as you expect. `Key2` evaluates to `string`. Even more confusing is that in both cases `typeof values2` will be `{ [x: string]: number; }`

Comment: That is true but if I use `[key in string]` then I still can't create a `type Key` that corresponds to the valid keys of the object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. By declaring `{ [key: string]: ... }` you're also getting rid of any information about what the keys are. You can either (a) declare the keys at compile time as in the first example or as a union or enum, etc. or (b) not declare the type of keys (or declare them broadly as `string`'s) but then you cannot get a list of what keys are defined on the object at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const values2: {
    [key: string]: number;
} = {
    x: 5,
    y: 6,
};

type Key2 = keyof typeof values2;  // number | string
```

> This doesn't make a lot of sense because the values2 object is being declared as having its key always be a string.
>
> What could be causing this?

`number` was added to `keyof` [in this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23592). I don't know the reasons, but the intent is that for index signature `{[key: string]: whatever}`, `keyof` does indeed include `number`, but for mapped type `{[key in string]: whatever}` `keyof` is only `string`.

Quotes from PR:

> Given an object type X, keyof X is resolved as follows:
>
> If X contains a string index signature, keyof X is a union of string, number, and the literal types representing symbol-like properties, otherwise
>
> ...
>
> In a mapped type { [P in K]: XXX }, each string literal type in K introduces a property with a string name, each numeric literal type in K introduces a property with a numeric name, and each unique symbol type in K introduces a property with a unique symbol name. Furthermore, if K includes type string, a string index signature is introduced, and if K includes type number, a numeric index signature is introduced.

Next question:

> And how can I declare an object that is similar to values2 (as in, I restrict what the type of the objects's values is), and then grab the valid keys as I am doing for the values object?

Why do you think that the only valid keys for `values2` are only `x` and `y`? Any key could be added afterwards. Unlike `values`, this compiles without any errors:

```
const values2: {
    [key: string]: number;
} = {
    x: 5,
    y: 6,
};

values2.z = 7; // ok
```